# Implementing a high pass filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, digital-filters

I am trying to implement a high pass digital filter in MATLAB.

High pass filter:

```
function [hd,n] = idl_highPass(wc,N)

if mod(N,2)==0

  a = N/2; 
else

  a = (N-1)/2;

end

m = 0:1:N-1;

n = m-a+eps;

hd = -sin(wc.*n)./(pi.*n);

end
```

I use the `freqz()` function to find the DTFT(or frequency response)of the filter but I am not getting what I expected

```
[h1,n] = idl_highPass(pi,5);

subplot(2,2,1);

w = -pi:0.01:pi;

H1 = freqz(h1,1,w);

plot(w,H1);
```

I am getting this:[image]

which is clearly not the frequency response of a digital high-pass filter.What could be causing this?

**UPDATE**

with wc<pi(normalized) in semilog scale:

[image]

the result is a lowpass which isnt the desired result.

Comment: Please see my answer and @DanBoschen's. You have the wrong high-pass impulse response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this into a highpass filter, multiply the impulse response by $(-1)^n$ which will serve to mirror the spectrum from being a low pass to a high pass (or optionally as @Jdip has demonstrated in the other answer here which is just as good of a solution: subtract the lowpass from a wire to get a highpass). The OP has multiplied by $(-1)$ instead of $(-1)^n$ and further has passed in $\pi$ as the cutoff frequency $\omega_c$: that is right at Nyquist, the cutoff frequency needs to be well below that.

Below is my code for the ideal impulse response for a low pass and high pass filter (in Python but easy to convert to Matlab):

```
def lowpass(fc, N):
    # fc: frequency cutoff between 0 and 0.5 (normalized frequency with fs=1)
    # N: Number of coefficients, can be even or odd
    n = np.arange(-(N-1)/2,(N-1)/2 + 1)
    return 2 * fc * np.sinc(2*fc*n)

def highpass(fc, N):
    # fc: frequency cutoff between 0 and 0.5 (normalized frequency with fs=1)
    # N: Number of coefficients, must be odd only for symmetric type 1 filter
    if N%2-1:
        #even
        raise ValueError("N must be odd")
    n = np.arange(-(N-1)/2,(N-1)/2 + 1)
    return lowpass(0.5-fc, N) * (-1)**n
```

I recommend multiplying the above with a window (Kaiser window is one of my favorites for filter implementation) for better filter performance, which will result in the cutoff frequency chosen to be the -6 dB cutoff.

Comment: But it looks like more of a band pass...

Comment: I have learnt that the frequency response of a high pass filter is  -sin(wc(n-M))/pi(n-M)

Comment: Yes but it outputs the frequency response.Look at my code the output of idl_highPass exists in the time domain.

Comment: But my notes say it is , how is that even possible?

Comment: The output of idl_highPass gives the impulse response of the digital filter as you can see it  is in the time domain , not the frequency domain.I get the output of my function and use the freqz() afterwards.

Comment: your last comment made me realize what I was doing wrong.If I set wc<pi then it works just fine.

Comment: I plotted abs(H1).

Comment: Ok so I think we’re on the same page, please update your code to change the -sin… to (-1)^n sin… and you’ll have your high pass!

Comment: Oh nice thank you it worked!

Comment: JDIPs approach would work too :(equivalent to “subtract a lowpass from a wire or mirror the spectrum as I had done

Comment: (Let’s delete the long thread of comments other than the last two as the moderators get flagged if there are long winded discussions on posts… which they discourage)

Answer (score 1):

1. The cut-off specified is $\pi$, meaning normalized Nyquist. It needs
   to be $<\pi$
2. You need to take the absolute value of the output from `freqz`:
   `plot(w,abs(H1));`
3. The impulse response for a high-pass filter is $$h[n] = \delta[n] -
   \frac{\sin(\omega_c\cdot(n-M))}{\pi\cdot(n-M)}$$ with $\omega_c =
   2\pi f_c$ and $f_c$ is the normalized cut-off ($0\leq f_c < 0.5$)

   Equivalently: $$h[n] = \delta[n] - 2f_c \cdot \text{sinc}(2f_c\cdot
   (n-M))$$

Updated Matlab code:

```
[h1,h1_windowed,n] = idl_highPass(pi*0.4,20);

w = (0:0.01:pi);
H1 = freqz(h1,1,w);
H1_windowed = freqz(h1_windowed,1,w);

figure(1)
clf
plot(w/pi,abs(H1));
hold on
grid on
plot(w/pi,abs(H1_windowed));
xlabel('Normalized frequency ( 1 = Nyquist (fs/2) )')
legend('rectangular windowed', 'hamming window')

function [hd,hd_windowed,n] = idl_highPass(wc,N)

if mod(N,2)==0
  a = N/2; 
  delta_n = [zeros(1,a) 1 zeros(1,a-1)]
else
  a = (N-1)/2;
  delta_n = [zeros(1,a) 1 zeros(1,a)]
end

m = 0:1:N-1;

n = m-a+eps;

hd = delta_n - sin(wc.*n)./(pi.*n);

% you should window this:
hd_windowed = hd .* hamming(N)';

end
```